# How to fetch only phone number contacts from Android device

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor, contactscontract

I am following this example [retrieve list of contacts](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) to retrieve contacts from android device.
It gives all the contacts which includes email contacts and some empty contacts.

I tried modifying ContactsContract like `ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER`in the projection and selection to get mobile contacts but nothing worked out.

```
String[] PROJECTION = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, SORT_ORDER,ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
```

String SELECTION =         ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +                 "<>''" + " AND "ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1";

Any idea to get only contacts which has mobile numbers?

Comment: use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: @pskink i tried passing Phone.CONTENT_URI in selection but gives unrecognized token exception.

Comment: Why do you have SORT_ORDER and HAS_PHONE_NUMBER in projection ? HAS_PHONE_NUMBER should be in selection - since you seem to be wanting to select based on it. Use selection = "HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1" and pass appropriate sort order in the correct parameter for query.

Comment: Changing ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI to ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI and adding HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1 in Selection instead of Projection fixed this, @RocketRandom thanks for your hint.

Comment: but i do get  same contact multiple times, any suggestion to avoid that

Answer (score 3):

I have created this library to solve all your queries. It will only save contacts with at least one email or phone number. Also it will remove duplicates from emails and phone numbers from same contacts (created by 3rd party apps like whatsapp).

Suggestions are welcome.

Link : https://github.com/raghavsatyadev/ContactFetcher/

Comment: Thanks,
just it crashes at line no : 34 in Helper.java
number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(number, "IN").replaceAll("\\s+", "");

Everything else works like charm !

how can we search in this ?

Comment: @kathan shah I have added a library on given link that I have created, please check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get all contact names and numbers

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String contactName=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```

Comment: this really works where we can avoid getting email contacts, but 1.how to sort by display names in this query 2. how to eliminates repeated phone number

Comment: You can take advantage of the Collections class to perform the sort and other operations

Answer (score 0):

Show only contacts with phone number and open contact list intent:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); // Uri.parse("content://contacts")
// Show only user contacts with phone numbers
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show only user contacts with phone numbers
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

Get the phone number from response/contact:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                // show error msg
                return;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            if (column >= 0) {
                String phoneNo = cursor.getString(column);
                sendSmsMessage(phoneNo);
            } else {
                // show error msg
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure, you also handle runtime permissions in API 23+

```
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```